# Have a dll project, can I force it to be linked to a static library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

wondering how to generate static library. Some quick method to turn a dll output to static lib?

Comment: rephrase: 'to be _linked_ into a static library'

Comment: take look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390270/how-can-i-manage-building-library-projects-that-produce-both-a-static-lib-and-a-d/4687396#4687396

Comment: Note that this may not always work. For instance, `DllMain` obviously won't be called any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Properties, go to Configuration Properties -> General.  Change 'Configuration Type' to 'Static library'.  You may need to change the use of MFC (if you are using it), to static.

Comment: if changed to static library, is all the dependencies be linked to it like visual c++ runtime?

Comment: @user705414 - Your executable will need to link any additional library depenencies (like the DLL used to do).